# Push varaibles into an array with containing variables - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, push

I have a code

```
var myArray = []

myArray.push( { "bob" : { "banana" : "yellow" } })

console.log(myArray)
```

which returns

```
{
    "bob": {
        "banana": "yellow"
    }
}
```

Now, I want to change the variables like this:

```
var myArray = []

var name = "bob"
var fruit = "banana"
var fruitcolor = "yellow"

myArray.push( { name : { fruit : fruitcolor } })

console.log(myArray)
```

but it doesn't return the same result. How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: `myArray.push( { [name] : { [fruit] : fruitcolor } })`. Use bracket notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set a string as a key of an object you have to use `bracket notation`

Replace

```js
myArray.push( { name : { fruit : fruitcolor } })
```

with :

```js
myArray.push( { [name] : { [fruit] : fruitcolor } })
```